# Store BigInteger into Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, biginteger

Due to mathematica constraints I've to use the BigInteger class to represent values.

After some calculations I would like to store the result (given by 2x BigInteger instances) into Mysql...

What is the best datatype to store such object ?

I was thinking about using a Blob to store the binary format of those results (128 bits) ? But I would like to avoid unnecessary type conversions.

Comment: Isn't bigint enough? (is just 8 bytes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using a Blob and then the `BigInteger(byte[] val)` constructor to go from byte array to BigInteger, and the `BigInteger#toByteArray()` method for the other way.

Comment: what about comparisons. I want to store and compare biginteger.

Comment: As far as I know, mysql does not have support for arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 7):

```
MySQL Type      Java Type
----------------------------------------
CHAR            String
VARCHAR         String
LONGVARCHAR     String
NUMERIC         java.math.BigDecimal
DECIMAL         java.math.BigDecimal
BIT             boolean
TINYINT         byte
SMALLINT        short
INTEGER         int
BIGINT          long
REAL            float
FLOAT           double
DOUBLE          double
BINARY          byte []
VARBINARY       byte []
LONGVARBINARY   byte []
DATE            java.sql.Date
TIME            java.sql.Time
TIMESTAMP       java.sql.Tiimestamp
```

[Reference](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/mapping-mysql-data-types-in-java.shtml)

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In order to store `bigInteger` values in MySQL, we can store as strings:

1. Convert `biginteger` to `string`:

   ```
   String s=bigint_value.toString();
   ```
2. Store `s` in table field which is of type `text`; e.g. if we store `s` in a table named `big_values` having field `big_value_as_string`:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE big_values (big_value_as_string text);
   ```

   The value is now stored.

To retrieve we must:

1. Retrieve string value from table:

   ```
   String bg = rs.getString("big_value_as_string");
   ```
2. Convert the string to `bigInteger` type:

   ```
   BigInteger b = new BigInteger(bg);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL has a BIGINT data type as shown in: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

You can try to use the BIGINT for that rather then doing conversion to binary formats which makes it whole lot more complex to my opinion.

Comment: The BIGINT datatype from MySQL can't hold my value ! 2^128 > 18446744073709551615 (max BIGINT unsigned value) !

Comment: This isn't really BigInteger anymore I guess... it's well more than the specific size of BigInteger.

Comment: BigInteger has different meanings in different contexts. The question is tagged "java", where BigInteger means arbitrary precision.

Comment: @thotheolh java's primitive long has the same range as mysql's bigint. java's biginteger is designed for values bigger than long and so for values bigger than mysql's bigint