# how to store public key mysql using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I need to store public key in my MySQL DB. I have the following:

```
 rsaModulus=rsaPk.getModulus();
```

The method `getModulus()`  returns BigInt. But, when I use `preparedstatement` in order to insert the value in the table, I can not find the approperiate method to do that (i.e, similar to `toString`, `toInt`). I need to retrieve this public key and do some mathematical calculations later. That's why, I don't think storing it as String would be a good idea. Also, `toLong` did not work as the field in the DB is defined as BigInt. Is there any solutions for this problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files, like keys and certificates generally are stored as a bite array.
This can be done with a blob collumn.

Mysql doc shows about these java type and mysql type relation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

If you are able to get your public key as a byte[], use like this sample code:

```
...
   InputStream is = PapelServiceTest.class.getResourceAsStream("MY_FILE_HERE");
   byte[] pkBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

   String query = "INSERT INTO my_table (my_key_col) VALUES (?)";
   PreparedStatement pstat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   pstat.setBytes(1, pkBytes);
   pstat.execute();
...
```

Comment: Which is better, store it in DB as Varbibnary or longblob ?

Comment: `pstat.setString(1, pkBytes);` does not work. pkBytes is array of bytes, not String.

Comment: I don't know why you use input stream. What if I don't want to use files? I have the value stored in variable and wants to store it as Blob directly. Can't I do this ?

Comment: Defining the public key as a byte[] in Java & Blob in MySQL DB solved the problem. Except that, in your solution you read the value from file, while I didn't need this as the public key is already stored in a variable. I just needed to convert the type.

Comment: You're right "pstat.setString(1, pkBytes);" won't work, I copied some part of code from other place, changed it a little bit but I hadn't tested it. In that case, I used InputStreat just as an example, if you already have the "byte[]", it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This thread has an interesting workaround using BLOB.

[Store BigInteger into Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374930/store-biginteger-into-mysql)

Perhaps you can use it.

PS. Next time, search SO first :)